# How to copy data from one sheet to another sheet in google sheets using dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have made individual months sheets and currently May is my active sheet in which I'm storing daily data. Now what I what is that when I select the order status as pending then the whole row data (order data) should be removed from the current sheet and moved to the sheet named Pending. For this purpose I've written the code given below which gives the error also given below:
**Code**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var value = range.getValue();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();

  // Check if the edited cell is in the May sheet and in the Status column
  if (sheet.getName() == "May" && col == 9) {
    var pendingSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Pending");

    // If the status is changed to "Pending", move the row to the Pending sheet
    if (value.toLowerCase() == "pending") {
      var rowValues = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
      pendingSheet.appendRow(rowValues);
      sheet.deleteRow(row);
    }
  }

  // Check if the edited cell is in the Pending sheet and in the Status column
  if (sheet.getName() == "Pending" && col == 9) {
    var maySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("May");

    // If the status is changed to "Complete", move the row to the May sheet
    if (value.toLowerCase() == "complete") {
      var rowValues = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
      maySheet.appendRow(rowValues);
      sheet.deleteRow(row);
    }
  }
}
```

**Error**
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
onEdit  @ Code.gs:2

**Here is my sheet sample data screenshot for better understanding**

[Data Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY3E6.png)

I've tried checking the sheets name, columns number etc but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to run it without supplying the event object.  Don't try to run from script editor just try editing the sheet and use toast and Logger to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

### onEdit(e). Detect change if Status is "Pending".

Cooper's comment is correct. onEdit(e) function, should have an object and if it is run on Google Apps Script what will happen is that it will have no object to work on if you have run it from Google Apps Script. I assume that you might have issues as well on let the code get in on your If statements `if (sheet.getName() == "May" && col == 9)` you might want to consider double checking the `col` value, based on the image you have shared col value should be 7.

### Sample Code for future Debugging:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var value = range.getValue();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
if (sheet.getName() == "May" && col == 7) {
    if (value.toLowerCase() == "pending") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Input logic of you result to the next sheet after this toast");
      
    }
```

For debugging functions that runs like onEdit(e) you can use the Toast to log your variables and string for checking. Here is what it looks like:

### [image]
Reference :

[onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

[Toast](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)